# Content form not shown in an eLearning site in Django

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I am trying to make a elearning site following an example from a book. It correctly worked upto showing a formset for course module. But when I adding functionality to add content to course modules. It gives error. The errors are:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/course/module/6/content/image/create/
Raised by:  courses.views.ContentCreateUpdateView
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Course
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateResponseMixin, View
from .forms import ModuleFormSet
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
from django.apps import apps
from .models import Module, Content

from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin,PermissionRequiredMixin

class OwnerMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(OwnerMixin, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class OwnerEditMixin(object):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(OwnerEditMixin, self).form_valid(form)

class OwnerCourseMixin(OwnerMixin, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Course
    fields = ['subject', 'title', 'slug', 'overview']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')

class OwnerCourseEditMixin(OwnerCourseMixin, OwnerEditMixin):
    fields = ['subject', 'title', 'slug', 'overview']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/form.html'

class ManageCourseListView(OwnerCourseMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/list.html'

class CourseCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,
                        OwnerCourseEditMixin,
                        CreateView):
    permission_required = 'courses.add_course'

class CourseUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,
                        OwnerCourseEditMixin,
                        UpdateView):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/form.html'
    permission_required = 'courses.change_course'

class CourseDeleteView(PermissionRequiredMixin,
                       OwnerCourseMixin, DeleteView):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')
    permission_required = 'courses.change_course'

class CourseModuleUpdateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/module/formset.html'
    course = None

    def get_formset(self, data=None):
        return ModuleFormSet(instance=self.course,
                                data=data)

    def dispatch(self, request, pk):
        self.course = get_object_or_404(Course,
                                        id=pk,
                                        owner=request.user)
        return super(CourseModuleUpdateView,
                     self).dispatch(request, pk)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = self.get_formset()
        return self.render_to_response({'course': self.course,
                                        'formset': formset})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = self.get_formset(data=request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('manage_course_list')
        return self.render_to_response({'course': self.course,
                                    'formset': formset})

class ContentCreateUpdateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    module = None
    model = None
    obj = None
    template_name = 'courses/manage/content/form.html'

    def get_model(self, model_name):
        if model_name in ['text', 'video', 'image', 'file']:
            return apps.get_model(app_label='courses',
                                model_name=model_name)
        return None

    def get_form(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
        Form = modelform_factory(model, exclude=['owner',
                                                'order',
                                                'created',
                                                'updated'])
        return Form(*args, **kwargs)

    def dispatch(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        self.module = get_object_or_404(Module,
                                        id=module_id,
                                        course__owner=request.user)
        self.model = self.get_model(model_name)
        if id:
            self.obj = get_object_or_404(self.model,
                                         id=id,
                                         owner=request.user)
        return super(ContentCreateUpdateView,
                     self).dispatch(request, module_id, model_name, id)

    def get(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model, instance=self.obj)
        return self.render_to_response({'form': form,
                                        'object': self.obj})

    def post(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model,
                             instance=self.obj,
                             data=request.POST,
                             files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.owner = request.user
            obj.save()
            if not id:
                # new content
                Content.objects.create(module=self.module,
                                       item=obj)
            return redirect('module_content_list', self.module.id)
        return self.render_to_response({'form': form,
                                        'object': self.obj})
```

Here is my courses/urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^mine/$',
        views.ManageCourseListView.as_view(),
        name='manage_course_list'),
    url(r'^create/$',
        views.CourseCreateView.as_view(),
        name='course_create'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',
        views.CourseUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='course_edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$',
        views.CourseDeleteView.as_view(),
        name='course_delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/module/$',
        views.CourseModuleUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='course_module_update'),
    url(r'^module/(?P<module_id>\d+)/content/(?P<model_name>\w+)/create/$',
        views.ContentCreateUpdateView.as_view(),
        name = 'module_content_create'),
    url(r'^module/(?P<module_id>\d+)/content/(?P<model_name>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/$',
        views.ContentCreateUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='module_content_update'),
]
```

Here is my courses/manage/content/form.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {% if object %}
        Edit content "{{ object.title }}"
    {% else %}
        Add a new content
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>
        {% if object %}
            Edit content "{{ object.title }}"
        {% else %}
            Add a new content
        {% endif %}
    </h1>

    <div class="module">
        <h2>Course info</h2>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p><input type="submit" value="Save content"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my project layout:
[image]

Could anyone suggest me why `http://127.0.0.1:8000/course/module/1/content/image/create/`  gives 404 error. I changed module id in the URL but no luck.

Comment: Don´t you should call http://127.0.0.1:8000/module/1/content/image/create/? Without course...

Comment: Elias, http://127.0.0.1:8000/course/module/1/content/image/create/ now worked. The reason was login issues.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ohid.

Answer (score 0):

In the `dispatch` method, you have:

```
self.module = get_object_or_404(Module,
                                id=module_id,
                                course__owner=request.user)
```

If this raises 404, then if means that the Module with id 6 (from the url), does not belong to the current user.

You can either to log in as the module's course's owner and try again, or change the id in `/course/module/6/content/image/create/` to one that you have permission to view.